# Efficiently convert Dict to NamedTuple in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to have an interface that accepts a `Dict` or a `NamedTuple` as input, but then always converts the input to a `NamedTuple`.

Given a `Dict`

```
julia> dd = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2)
Dict{Symbol,Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
```

I can covert it to a `NamedTuple` with

```
julia> (; dd...)
(a = 1, b = 2)
```

However, this both allocates a surprising (to me) amount

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime (; $dd...);
  1.033 μs (12 allocations: 896 bytes)
```

And it does not apply to nested `Dict`s, which I would like to convert to nested `NamedTuple`s

```
julia> dd_nested = Dict(:a => 1, :b => Dict(:x => 3, :y => 4))
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 2 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => Dict(:y=>4,:x=>3)

julia> (; dd_nested...)
(a = 1, b = Dict(:y => 4,:x => 3))
```

where the desired output is equal to

```
julia> (a = 1, b = (x = 3, y = 4))
(a = 1, b = (x = 3, y = 4))
```

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
unzip(d::Dict) = (;(p.first => unzip(p.second) for p in d)...)
unzip(d) = d
```

Sample test:

```
julia> unzip(dd)
(a = 1, b = (y = 4, x = 3))
```

Regarding memory allocations `NamedTupleTools.jl` seems to have a slightly smaller memory footprint. But in either case you are creating quite a bit of data structure here so most likely you will not be able to do it any cheaper.